# Can JDBCConnectionManager be used with JDBCRowSet?

Tags: xpages, xpages-extlib

I am trying to use `<xe:jdbcConnectionManager>` with `<xe:jdbcRowSet>`. Should this work? The book  (XPages Extension Library) seems to imply it should, but the example NSF (XPagesJDBC.nsf) does not contain any examples with that combination. Of course, the jdbcRowSet accepts `connectionManager` attribute.

I get this error:

```
com.ibm.xsp.FacesExceptionEx: Unknown ConnectionManager jdbcConnectionManager1
com.ibm.xsp.extlib.util.JdbcUtil.createManagedConnection(JdbcUtil.java:106)
com.ibm.xsp.extlib.jdbc.model.JdbcRowSetAccessor.findConnection(JdbcRowSetAccessor.java:467)
```

### EXTLIB CODE

The problem seems to be in JdbcUtil.java function findConnectionManager(). It returns null and that's why I get the above exception. Here's the function:

```
public static IJdbcConnectionManager findConnectionManager(FacesContext context, UIComponent from, String name) throws SQLException {
    UIComponent c = FacesUtil.getComponentFor(from, name);
    if(c!=null) {
        return (IJdbcConnectionManager)c;
    }
    return null;
}
```

The parameter `name` is not null since it is referenced in the exception message. The parameter `context`is not used at all. And the parameter `from`, if null, is acquired like this (on row 102): `from = context.getViewRoot();`.

Here's the function throwing the exception:

```
public static Connection createManagedConnection(FacesContext context, UIComponent from, String name) throws SQLException {
    if(from==null) {
        from = context.getViewRoot(); // ROW 102
    }
    IJdbcConnectionManager manager = findConnectionManager(context, from, name);
    if(manager==null) {
        throw new FacesExceptionEx(null,"Unknown ConnectionManager {0}",name); // ROW 106
    }
    return manager.getConnection();
}
```

### MY CODE

So, this works:

```
<xp:this.data>
<xe:jdbcRowSet var="jdbcRowSet1" maxRows="10"
  sqlQuery="SELECT * FROM test.reportcode;"
  connectionName="mysql_pooled">
</xe:jdbcRowSet>
</xp:this.data>
```

And this doesn't work:

```
<xe:jdbcConnectionManager id="jdbcConnectionManager1"               
  connectionName="mysql_pooled">
</xe:jdbcConnectionManager>

<xp:this.data>
<xe:jdbcRowSet var="jdbcRowSet1" maxRows="10"
  sqlQuery="SELECT * FROM test.reportcode;"
  connectionManager="jdbcConnectionManager1">
</xe:jdbcRowSet>
</xp:this.data>
```

Note that the connectionName is identical, and works perfectly when used directly by jdbcRowSet. The only change is replacing that attribute with a reference to jdbcConnectionManager using that same connectionName. The setup works also perfectly with the jdbcQuery datasource.

How can I make this work? Or can it be done?

Comment: in that xe:jdbcRowSet, did you try binding connectionManager="#{jdbcConnectionManager1}"?

Comment: @Frantisek, that produces error: "No connection manger, JNDI name or url is provided". The property's `<property-class>` in xsp-config is defined as _java.lang.String_. The function `createManagedConnection()` above is called only if this is true: `if(StringUtil.isNotEmpty(connectionManager))`.

Comment: My thought was to initiate binding to "force" creation of bean. That property requires variable name (as you pointed out in sources), so it does not work. Another idea: define that bean in faces-config instead of XP/CC source. A bit more complicated, but I try to avoid "on/before/after" script helpers at all costs.

Comment: Have you tried moving the data source to an inner panel?

Comment: @Tim: using an extra `<xp:panel>` indeed makes it work. Thanks, I'll accept that as an answer if you post one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**NOTE:** I'm guessing you know why adding a panel fixes the problem, but I'm including additional detail for the benefit of others who might encounter the same behavior.

Almost everything in XPages is processed hierarchically. So variables, data sources, and component references are often only valid within the context of a container.

Given the source code you listed in your question, the data source is attached to the "view root", so it's valid anywhere on that page (or Custom Control). As the page is evaluated at runtime, the root component will be processed first, and part of that evaluation is determining whether the data source attached to it needs to be created or already exists, based on its scope.

Once that's finished, it can start processing any child components, which -- again, in your example -- includes the `jdbcConnectionManager`.

This is why, as Panu mentioned, the data source can't refer to the component: it's attached to a parent.

But data sources can be associated with specific panels, not just view roots. If you add a `panel` as a sibling to the `jdbcConnectionManager` -- specifically, *below* it -- and move the data source to that `panel`, here's what then happens at runtime:

- Domino starts processing the view root; not much to do here now, so it just hands off control to its children.
- The first child is the `jdbcConnectionManager`, so whatever encoding needs to happen for that component occurs before dealing with the rest.
- Next, the panel is evaluated. This includes evaluating the data source, which can now refer to the connection manager component, since it has already been loaded.
- Finally, all of the panel's descendant components (its children, their children, and so on) are evaluated. So anything that needs to refer to the data source does need to be defined somewhere inside this panel, but the data source can refer to the connection manager without blowing up specifically because that component *isn't* inside the panel... it's already been processed by the time the panel is dealt with.

Comment: The `jdbcRowSet` is the datasource so did you mean `jdbcConnectionManager`?

Comment: A very clear explanation, thanks. However, i am puzzled as to why the setup works with a `jdbcQuery` datasource. There must be some difference in their initialization procedures (lazy vs. direct style).

Comment: That would be my guess as well. Since these data sources are part of the Extension Library, you could crack open the source code if you really want to know how they behave behind the scenes. :)

Answer (score 2):

The component `xe:jdbcConnectionManager` does not exist yet when `<xp:this.data>` is computed. Components often use XPage datasource and probably that's why datasource is computed before components are created.

You could try setting the `connectionManager` for example in `afterPageLoad` event.

**EDIT**

One thing to check is [SPR#MKEE86YD5L Also search for components that are within facets.](http://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/dw/lotus/Domino-Designer/JavaDocs/DesignerAPIs/com/ibm/xsp/util/FacesUtil.html#getComponentFor%28javax.faces.component.UIComponent,%20java.lang.String%29) Not sure if this has been fixed or not.

Comment: It seems indeed to be a timing issue (see @Tim's comment above). The `setConnectionManager()` function did not work, btw (it is just a setter for the String property).

Comment: Oh, and I could not unfortunately find that SPR :(

Answer (score 0):

it is because of sqljdbc driver bug. The code works fine with mysql.